# Allow us to set time of alerts

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

It seems that job alerts are set to be sent at 1AM EDT (unclear if it is set as EDT, or simply 5AM GMT). It would be much more convenient for me if they were to be sent out closer to 3PM GMT.

I would like a way to set the time schedule of alerts. Even a drop-down which allowed settings of which hour, or even which 3-hour block would be better than no option at all.

Comment: Ah yes, Eastern Daylight Time time! ;)

Comment: Look, I also have a PIN number and I use it with an ATM Machine.